# Add conditions to SVM

Tags: artificial-intelligence, svm

I am working on a project that use multi-class SVM classifier, i check some of the tools that perform multi classification using SVM, in these tools i need to insert training data and RBF parameters. can i add some constraints to the SVM like i want all the members of the class to meet some criteria. e.g. if i want to classify cars i want the price of all cars in class x < 500000. is this possible?
and if you know any place to start with to add conditions to SVM i will appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

SVM models do not allow any constraints like what you describe. Kernel methods are entirely based on a measure of distance, without rules or input constraints.

If you want such constraints you should consider decision trees/random forests and similar aproaches.

Comment: thnx for answering my question, but is there a method to convert any linear programming problem to SVM?

Comment: No. Because, like I said, SVM do not allow input constraints of any form. If you write your own solver/use standard QP solvers you could make *some* formulation which allows that, but it will not be an SVM.